# How to flag last friday or last day or month

Tags: r, date

I have a data frame of dates and the day of the week

```
> head(data)
         day   weekday
1 2016-01-01    Friday
4 2016-01-04    Monday
5 2016-01-05   Tuesday
6 2016-01-06 Wednesday
7 2016-01-07  Thursday
8 2016-01-08    Friday
```

here is the code:

```
data <- data.frame(day = seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2016-05-10"), "day"), 
                  weekday = weekdays(seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2016-05-10"), 
                                         "day")))
excludeDays <- c("Saturday", "Sunday")
data <- subset(data, !weekdays(data$day) %in% excludeDays) #exclude weekend
```

I would like to add 2 columns that flag the last friday in each month and the last day in the month regardless of what day it is.  How would you do that?

To be more specific:
I would like it to identify, only for my data, if the date is the last date in the month.  For example, if my data has dates in January 2016 and the last date in January I have is 1/20/2016 then that should be flagged as the last day in the month. Similarly I'd like to identify the last Friday in a month in my data not on a calendar.

Comment: anything specific in lubridate?

Comment: ceiling_date returns the first day of the next month. that won't work

Comment: try  lubridate::ceiling_date(x, unit = "month") - 1

Comment: That will return the last day in the month on a calendar but i would like it to identify, only for my data, if the date is the last date in the month.  For example, if my data has dates in January 2016 and the last date in January I have is 1/20/2016 then that should be flagged as the last day in the month. Similarly I'd like to identify the last Friday in a month in my data not on a calendar.

Comment: Then you need to do a group by calendar month and get the max date for each group.  Then do the same for Fridays (same code just filter to only look at Fridays).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the additional clarification and following the comment by @eminik the code below

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[, LastDayInMonth := day == max(day), by = .(year(day), month(day))]
data[, LastFridayInMonth := weekday == "Friday" & day == max(day), 
     by = .(year(day), month(day), weekdays(day))]
```

produces:

```
# show results (only relevant rows)
data[LastDayInMonth | LastFridayInMonth == TRUE]

          day  weekday LastDayInMonth LastFridayInMonth
1: 2016-01-29   Friday           TRUE              TRUE
2: 2016-02-26   Friday          FALSE              TRUE
3: 2016-02-29   Monday           TRUE             FALSE
4: 2016-03-25   Friday          FALSE              TRUE
5: 2016-03-31 Thursday           TRUE             FALSE
6: 2016-04-29   Friday           TRUE              TRUE
7: 2016-05-06   Friday          FALSE              TRUE
8: 2016-05-10  Tuesday           TRUE             FALSE
```

**Edit:** Code modified to account for change of years as requested by OP.

**Note:** `weekdays` returns a character vector of names *in the locale in use*. Therefore, the code only works if you are in an English locale. Otherwise, you may have to use `Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "English")` before.

Comment: I see that it works in your code but I can't get it to work in my real code

Comment: I get this warning and everything is false In `[.data.table`(data, , `:=`(LastDayInMonth, data$BUSINESS_DATE ==  ... :
  RHS 1 is length 507 (greater than the size (46) of group 1). The last 461 element(s) will be discarded.

Comment: the error is that if you extend the date range longer than 1 year the grouping does not work and everything is false.  Change the start date to 2014-01-01 instead of 2016-01-01 and you will see

Comment: Just needed to use this as the by: by = list(year(BUSINESS_DATE),month(BUSINESS_DATE) )   - Thank you.

Comment: is it possible to identify if the Friday is the 3rd Friday in the month?

Comment: Note that users may have to use `Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "English")` to get the code working if they are not already in an English locale.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `lubridate` for date calculations, but since you have missing days in between, I use `lead()` function from `dplyr` to find the next day (row) in the data.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
my.data <- tbl_df(data)
my.data <- my.data %>% 
    # First last day of month
    # get the next day in the data
    mutate(next.day = lead(day)) %>%
    # it's month is different
    mutate(LastDayInMonth = ifelse(month(day) != month(next.day), T, F)) %>%
    # Now Last Friday
    mutate(LastFridayInMonth = 
               ifelse( (wday(day) == 6) & # It's a Friday
                # Check the month of next Friday, different
                (month(lead(day, 5)) != month(day)
                 | is.na(lead(day, 5))), T, F))
```

Comment: When I do `tail(my.data)` I see `NA`s in `LastFridayInMonth ` on 2016-05-06 and in `LastDayInMonth` on 2016-05-10.

Comment: This logic works when there is **another** Friday ***after*** the specific target one to look at. For that special case, we should add more logic to find the last Friday in the whole data set.

Comment: The code is edited to cover the special case of last Friday in the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
data%>% 
  mutate(year = year(day),month= month(day)) %>%
  group_by(year, month) %>% 
  mutate(LastDayInMonth = max(day)==day)%>% 
  arrange(day) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(year, month, weekday) %>%
  mutate(LastWeekInMonth = row_number() ==  n(), 
         LastFriayInMonth = weekday =="Freitag" & LastWeekInMonth == 1) %>% 
  ungroup()%>%
  select(day, weekday, LastDayInMonth,LastFriayInMonth)
```

Same excerpt as above (%>% filter(LastDayInMonth | LastFriayInMonth == TRUE):

```
Source: local data frame [8 x 4]

         day    weekday LastDayInMonth LastFriayInMonth
      (date)     (fctr)          (lgl)            (lgl)
1 2016-01-29    Freitag           TRUE             TRUE
2 2016-02-26    Freitag          FALSE             TRUE
3 2016-02-29     Montag           TRUE            FALSE
4 2016-03-25    Freitag          FALSE             TRUE
5 2016-03-31 Donnerstag           TRUE            FALSE
6 2016-04-29    Freitag           TRUE             TRUE
7 2016-05-06    Freitag          FALSE             TRUE
8 2016-05-10   Dienstag           TRUE            FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require(data.table)

lfom<-function(d){
  x<-seq(min(d),max(d),by=1)
  fri<-which(wday(x)==6)
  mend<-which(mday(x)==1)-1
  d %in%  x[fri[findInterval(mend,fri)]]
}

ldom<-function(d){
  x<-seq(min(d),max(d),by=1)
  mend<-which(mday(x)==1)-1
  d %in%  x[mend]
}


data <-data.frame(
  day = seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2016-05-10"), "day"), 
  weekday = weekdays(seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2016-05-10"), "day"))
)
excludeDays <- c("Saturday", "Sunday")
data <- data.table(subset(data, !weekdays(data$day) %in% excludeDays)) #exclude weekend
data$lfom<-lfom(data$day)
data$ldom<-ldom(data$day)
```