# How to convert "1987 January" string to Date object?

Tags: r, date

I have some data given in months, and would like to convert them to a date object.

I've tried `as.Date(as.character(data$Date), format = '%Y %B'` to no success. How can this be solved?

Code & Data

```
> head(SE.10Y)
           Date  SE.10Y
1  1987 January 11.7385
2 1987 February 11.5000
3    1987 March 11.2586
4    1987 April 11.2385
5      1987 May 11.8153
6     1987 June 11.8120

> dput(droplevels(head(SE.10Y)))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 4L), .Label = c("1987 April", 
"1987 February", "1987 January", "1987 June", "1987 March", "1987 May"
), class = "factor"), SE.10Y = c(11.7385, 11.5, 11.2586, 11.2385, 
11.8153, 11.812)), .Names = c("Date", "SE.10Y"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

> as.Date(as.character(head(SE.10Y)$Date), format = '%Y %B')
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: You need a day to have a date.  Those are just months and years.  I have seen people solve this by simply pasting a 1 at the end to denote the first day of the month, making a complete date. `as.Date(paste(data$Date, 1), format = "%Y %B %d")`

Comment: Is there any way I can convert all the text values ("January") to numbers? In that case I can make a yearmon variable which would be fine.

Comment: I edited my comment, try refreshing the page

Comment: Thank you, however when I run your code (which I think should be right. I get alot of NA values, and only some dates are correctly returned.

Comment: The NA output is probably due to locale setting I realize.

Comment: Concerning locale settings, please, see my note in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37685950/3817004). The remark on names of weekdays applies to names of months as well.

Comment: @uncool, Regarding your comment about `yearmon`, try this: `library(zoo); as.yearmon("1987 January", "%Y %B")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want the beginning of the month (in UTC) and using `lubridate` you get:

```
dates <- c("1987 April",  "1987 February", "1987 January", "1987 June", "1987 March", "1987 May")
lubridate::ymd(paste(dates,"01"))
[1] "1987-04-01 UTC" "1987-02-01 UTC" "1987-01-01 UTC" "1987-06-01 UTC" "1987-03-01 UTC" "1987-05-01 UTC"
```